# My storage partition set aside for docker is not recognised as a valid block device

Tags: docker, linode, openshift-origin

I'm trying to setup an openshift cluster on linode. I have set aside some disk space (via linode admin dashboard) for docker to use for storage. Unfortunately, I can't get it to be recognised as a valid block device.

My one server has the following setup:

```
# df
/dev/sda       ext4      20131844 2467892  16623616  13% /
/dev/sdb       ext4      30799868   44992  30424248   1% /mnt/sdb-mnt
```

[As per RedHat guidelines](https://docs.okd.io/3.6/install_config/install/host_preparation.html#configuring-docker-storage), I have the following configuration:

```
# vim /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup
DEVS=/dev/vdb
VG=docker-vg
```

I am getting the following error:

```
# docker-storage-setup
INFO: Volume group backing root filesystem could not be determined
ERROR: /dev//dev/vdb is not a valid block device.
```

My best guess is that I must perform some step that was skipped when provisioning the storage.

Comment: You have to provide your actual device. You don't seem to have one named vdb.

Comment: You can check the available devices with `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I typo'd the /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup file.

The correct block device path was /dev/sdb and not /dev/vdb.

Another problem visible in the above is that the partition is ext4 formatted. The following fixed that if it helps anyone.

```
umount /dev/sdb
wipefs -a /dev/sdb
docker-storage-setup
```